# How can i target a subset of ECS tasks for stop operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, task, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, group

In my architecture, a single "job" may require N "tasks".
A user can start a job, allow many tasks to begin, then later cancel the job all together.
When this happens, i need to stop all tasks for that job.

I am having trouble determining the best way to "group" my tasks in a way that i can reference them by JobId.

I noticed that taskDefinitions have a "group" attribute, but i can not find an easy way to perform bulk operations on like-group tasks as i might expect.

I am looking for an equivilent to the kubectl command:

```bash
kubectl delete job -l jobId=123
```

or

```bash
kubectl delete pod -l jobId=123
```

I thought perhaps task-sets might be what i am looking for, but the more i read about them, the more confused i am about what they are.

I was hoping for something like

```bash
aws ecs delete-task --group jobId=123
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to delete specific ECS tasks by a single command like that. If you look at the `aws ecs stop-task` command (there is no `delete-task` command) you will see that you have to specify the Task ID, there is no other options you can pass to select the task(s) to be stopped.

When you run the tasks you could add an AWS Tag to the task with the Job ID:

```
aws ecs run-task --tags jobId=123`
```

You would then have to call [aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html) to get all the tasks with a specific Job ID tag. That returns the full task ARNs. You should then be able to pass those Task ARNs as the task ID to `aws ecs stop-task`.

---

Alternatively you might consider adding some task tracking logic to your application so you don't have to rely on what the AWS API exposes for your tasks. You could capture the task IDs that come back in the `run task` response, and place those somewhere like a DymamoDB table, along with the JobID. Then when a job is cancelled it would be a simple matter of querying your database for the task IDs that correspond to that job, and then calling `stop-task` with those IDs.